# Entity Framework throwing Stack Overflow exceptions

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2012, entity-framework-6

Entity Framework keeps throwing this exception.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occured
>   in mscorlib.dll

The exception appears in the generated context class code when I call a stored procedure.

There is no specific procedure it happens with and even simple procedures fail.

I have tried deleting the EF model and recreating with no luck.

This has worked fine in the past, no idea why it has suddenly started!

All help appreciated.

example EF generated code with the problem:

```
    public virtual ObjectResult<GetVariant_Result> GetVariant(Nullable<int> variantId)
    {
        var variantIdParameter = variantId.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("VariantId", variantId) :
            new ObjectParameter("VariantId", typeof(int));

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<GetVariant_Result>("GetVariant", variantIdParameter);
    }
```

The matching result class:

```
public partial class GetVariant_Result
{
    public int VariantId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int ModelId { get; set; }
    public string ModelName { get; set; }
    public int BuildId { get; set; }
    public string ModelCode { get; set; }
    public string ProductionStart { get; set; }
    public string ProductionEnd { get; set; }
    public int EngineId { get; set; }
    public int FuelTypeId { get; set; }
    public string FuelTypeDescription { get; set; }
    public int TransmissionId { get; set; }
    public string TransmissionDescription { get; set; }
}
```

The procedure that matches this code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetVariant]
    @VariantId int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT      Variant.VariantId           VariantId,
                Variant.[Description]       [Description],
                Model.ModelId               ModelId,
                Model.Name                  ModelName,
                Build.BuildId               BuildId,
                Build.ModelCode             ModelCode,
                Build.ProductionStart       ProductionStart,
                Build.ProductionEnd         ProductionEnd,
                Engine.EngineId             EngineId,
                FuelType.FuelTypeId         FuelTypeId,
                FuelType.[Description]      FuelTypeDescription,
                Transmission.TransmissionId TransmissionId,
                Transmission.[Description]  TransmissionDescription
    FROM        Variant
    INNER JOIN  Build
    ON          Build.BuildId = Variant.BuildId
    INNER JOIN  Model
    ON          Model.ModelId = Build.ModelId
    INNER JOIN  Engine
    ON          Engine.EngineId = Variant.EngineId
    INNER JOIN  FuelType
    ON          FuelType.FuelTypeId = Engine.FuelTypeId
    INNER JOIN  Transmission
    ON          Transmission.TransmissionId = Variant.TransmissionId
    WHERE       Variant.VariantId = @VariantId

END
```

Comment: can you try to execute above code with ExecuteStoreQuery instead ExecuteFunction

Comment: I'll have to edit the generated code, but sure I'll try it.

Comment: Do you get a stack trace?  If so, please add it.  If not, you should be able to get something in the callstack in the debugger -- show that if possible.

Comment: also try this code if needed.
SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter("@firstName", "Foo");
SqlParameter  param2 = new SqlParameter("@lastName", "Bar");
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("sp_name @firstName, @lastName",     param1, param2);

Comment: Using ExecuteStoreQuery gives another exception: An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in ASP.NET_MVC5_Bootstrap3_3_4_LESS.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: No mapping exists from object type System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectParameter to a known managed provider native type.

Comment: No stack trace because of the stack overflow, but the call stack is very telling. It looks like I have a circular reference going on...

Comment: @KirkWoll gave me the answer, it's a never-ending loop of hell.